# How to detect when the scrollbars appear? C#

Tags: c#, events, scrollbars

Is there a way or an event to solve this?
well specifically its for a flow layout panel

Comment: The answer probably depends upon what control you're talking about (a Form, a Panel etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a FlowLayoutPanel, you could check whether the `Bottom` property of the last control in the panel is more than the panel's height.

Alternatively, try checking `VerticalScroll.Visible` (I haven't tried that, but it shoud do what you're looking for)

Comment: Yes, the VerticalScroll.Visible indicates if the scrollbar will be displayed or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When scroll bars appear, the Resize event is fired. As I do a U.S.D.A. Certified Buttload of Custom Node Painting, I need to know. So… I… do… this…

```
  private bool vScrollVisible = false;      

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  private void TreeViewClean_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if(VScrollVisible())
     {
        if (!vScrollVisible)
        {
           vScrollVisible = true;
           Refresh();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        if(vScrollVisible)
        {
           vScrollVisible = false;
           Refresh();
        }
     }
  }
```