# Disable mousewheel scrolling on panel. c#

Tags: c#

So, i have `pictureBox` on `panel` in windows form.

I`m wanna zoom-in/out image in pictureBox by mouseScroll:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs ea)
        {
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.None;            
            if (ea.Delta > 0)
                {                    
                    if ((pictureBox.Width < (15 * this.Width)) && (pictureBox.Height < (15 * this.Height)))
                    {
                        pictureBox.Width = (int)(pictureBox.Width * 1.25);
                        pictureBox.Height = (int)(pictureBox.Height * 1.25);
                        
                        pictureBox.Top = (int)(ea.Y - 1.25 * (ea.Y - pictureBox.Top));
                        pictureBox.Left = (int)(ea.X - 1.25 * (ea.X - pictureBox.Left));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((pictureBox.Width > (pictureBox.Width)) && (pictureBox.Height > (pictureBox.Height)))
                    {
                        pictureBox.Width = (int)(pictureBox.Width / 1.25);
                        pictureBox.Height = (int)(pictureBox.Height / 1.25);

                        pictureBox.Top = (int)(ea.Y - 0.80 * (ea.Y - pictureBox.Top));
                        pictureBox.Left = (int)(ea.X - 0.80 * (ea.X - pictureBox.Left));
                    }
                }
            
        }
```

But now, when i zoom-in panel makes scrollbars enable and i can do anything by the wheel except scrool image in panel.

How i can disable scroll by wheel on panel but keep zoomin-out by wheel on pictureBox

Comment: The `if` inside `else` doesn't make sense (always `false`), I guess it's a "work in progress" and should be ignored, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Simple and functional way to zoom picturebox images with scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270144/c-simple-and-functional-way-to-zoom-picturebox-images-with-scroll-bars)

Comment: See duplicate, my suggestion is the same as the answer there: don't resize `PictureBox`, rather learn to scale images directly (and it's [not hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916023/1997232)).

Comment: @Sinatr so, anyway, if i resize image i`ll have same problem with scrollbars isnt it?

Comment: @Sinatr i can change size by both method - resize picturebox or image directly. Its really not hard) But both methods have problems with panel scrollbars

Comment: Was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21261285/1997232)? I'd control scrollbars manually and redraw image e.g. as background of custom control. Putting *huge* control inside panel with scrollbars just doesn't feels right to me.

Comment: @Sinatr i whant able to zoomin/out by the mouseWheel and navigate in panel by click and move scrollbars, not by the wheel. But now i use mousewheel to zoomin and when scrollbars are enable i cant zoomin/out by wheel, but can navigate in panel by the wheel

Comment: Just put the logic inside [WheelessPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261922/1997232) to see if [scrollbar is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1522995/1997232) and either call base or zoom.

Comment: @Sinatr oh, thx. It`s really work now. Sorry for my bad eng)